# Canvas is not maximize when window maximized

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, canvas

There is border out side canvas Tag, Now I want to maximize the size of canvas according to window maximized

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AllowDrop="True" Background="Transparent" PreviewDragOver="canvas_DragOver" PreviewDrop="canvas_Drop" Width="600" Height="500">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tb" AllowDrop="True" Text="WorkBench" TextAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="20" Canvas.Left="258" Canvas.Top="0" ToolTip="Drag and Drop Tools Here" />
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: You have your Canvas set to `Width="600" Height="500"`, you will have to remove that if you want it to get bigger/smaller

Comment: I removed height and width but still it is not coming

Comment: instead if width and hieght try using minwidth and min hieght

Comment: I tried with MinWidth and MinHeight also, Its not working

Comment: How about `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` set to `Stretch` on your ScrollViewer?